# MySQL search with multiple values and multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a search engine whereby anyone can search for a service at a place and get the result for instance someone inputs "restaurants @LA" the result shows all the restaurant at LA.

I have two tables holding the restaurant name and another holding the location they are related with an id. In my SQL I am using `LEFT JOIN` but am really having a hard time writing an SQL query to solve this problem.

```
public function sec($searchwords){
$searchwords=trim($searchwords);

$searchwords=preg_split('/[\s]+/',$searchwords);


//after removing whitespaces covert d array back to string
$searchwordz=false;
foreach($searchwords as $searchword){
$searchwordz .= $searchword;
}


//separate d strings from location
$location=false;
preg_match("/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $searchwordz, $matches);
foreach($matches as $values){
$location.=substr($values, 1);
}

//remove location from the rest of the string
$keywords=preg_replace("/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/",'',$searchwords);


$returned_result=array();

$where="";

$where1="";

$total_keywords=count($keywords);

foreach($keywords as $key =>$keyword){

$where.="place.place_name  LIKE :place_name AND location.state LIKE :state";    
$where1.="place.description LIKE :description AND location.state LIKE :state";

if($key != ($total_keywords - 1)){

$where.=" AND ";
$where1.=" AND ";   

}

}

//echo $where;



$sbl=$dabase->prepare("SELECT place.place_name, place.description, location.location FROM place    LEFT JOIN location ON place.mid=member.mid WHERE $where ORDER BY place.time");

$sbl->execute(array(
':place_name' => '%'.$keyword.'%',
':state' => '%'.$location.'%'
));

//echo $sbl;

if($sbl->rowCount() == 0){

    echo "No item found";

}

else{

while($data=$sbl->fetch()){

echo $data['place_name']."<br/>";   

echo $data['description']."<br/>";

}

}
}
```

So far this code works but not as I expected, it's supposed to return results related to the search input and its location if location is mentioned but it returns everything both related on not related it just does not limit it to the related search result or results.

Comment: Unless you provide some data or setup a SQL fiddle we're going to have a really hard time too.

Comment: What query are  you trying?

Comment: @halfer i have edited my question please take a look @ my codes.

Comment: Can you break this down into a query that you enter into your MySQL client, so you can debug the SQL separately? If you can echo it out so you can paste it into your question that would help also - at present someone would have to guess the format of your database, create it, add in test data, copy your code into a web folder, run it, and make changes in order to answer you - and that's too much work.

Comment: @ halfer just echoed the sql statement

Comment: @halfer can u help me now

Comment: @halfer i dont know how to use sql fiddle

Comment: @halfer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c351/1 check the sql fiddle

Comment: You are 80% of the way there. Now add some `INSERT` statements on the left - this is your test data. Then adjust your query on the right so it works - this will give readers something to test and to modify. (Please be wiling to make this kind of effort for all of your questions. If you do, then you will have a much easier time on Stack Overflow. Your readers want to help, but they want to see your solid effort first).

Comment: @halfer it works but i think its my php code thats causing my error please compare my sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fd86/3 and my question here and see if you can understand what i want to do

Comment: I've added an answer, and deleted a few of my old comments. (By the way, I notice you are using `BIGINT` to store telephone numbers. It is usual to use `VARCHAR` here, so it preserves the initial zero, and other things people put in numbers, like spaces and dashes. The type you have chosen will work, but it depends on whether you are OK with its limitations).

Comment: @halfer i want to write a small search engine that user can search a place and using the @ symbol along side it to find a restaurant in a particular area for instance someone can type in the search box "kfc @sandwell" this is what am trying to do using php to separate the name and location checking it in the database and the restaurant name and there location are in separate tables but are related with there id's then i will return matches if any am using left join in sql so that even if there is no kfc in that location it can still return kfc in other location, can you help me modify my code

Comment: @rapulu: in general we try to avoid "do it for me" requests, as it makes it difficult for a poster to learn anything from the experience. However I have spotted another problem, which I have added to my answer. Please read all of it, and carry out the specific debugging investigations I have suggested. That will be very good practice for you.

Comment: @halfer yes i plan on adding $where1 but thats after the first one works the way i want

Comment: @halfer thanks for your help and guidance, i have finally resolved my problem through debugging my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done on creating a Fiddle, that's very useful. You have now shown conclusively that your query works, so the issue has been narrowed down to your PHP code. In retrospect you could have done this in phpMyAdmin or your MySQL console client, but you have learned a very useful skill, so the time has hardly been wasted.

To continue your debugging, I would start by changing this code:

```
$sbl=$dabase->prepare("SELECT place.place_name, place.description, location.location FROM place    LEFT JOIN location ON place.mid=member.mid WHERE $where ORDER BY place.time");
```

Change it to:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT place.place_name, place.description, location.location
    FROM place
    LEFT JOIN location ON place.mid=member.mid
    WHERE $where
    ORDER BY place.time
";
$sbl=$dabase->prepare($sql);
echo $sql;
```

That will do the same thing, but it will print out the SQL you are running. You will notice I have formatted the query as well, so it is more readable in your IDE (and on this site too). I recommend writing all queries like this if you can.

My guess is that clauses you believe have been submitted to the query have not been added. Make this change and find out.

---

Edit: also, you are compiling two `WHERE` clauses, `$where` and `$where1`, but then you only use the first of these. If you intended to add in both then you'll need to edit the second one in.